# React Testing Library - can't find anchor element by role

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have the following code:

```
    <div className="button">
      <a href={SOME_URL}>
      ...
      ...
      </a>
    </div>
```

And in my test, if i try to do:

```
const link = screen.getByRole('link');
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "link"
```

Running `screen.debug()`, i'm getting the following:

```
          <div
            class="button"
          >
            <a>
```

So how come it can't find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The a[href] has a default role of link...

[source](https://fae.disability.illinois.edu/rulesets/ROLE_12/)

You'll need to add an `href` to the `<a>`.

Comment: It does have an `href` like i mentioned in the code snippet, i'm not sure why it doesn't appear when i print `screen.debug()`?

Comment: Hmm, can you create this issue with a simple component that renders a `<a href="https://google.com">link</a>` to ensure that `screen.debug()` gives you back the same output without the `href`?

Comment: Yeah it does work with a plain string - any reason for why it won't render it if i use a JS variable like in my code snippet?

Comment: Yes, if that variable is `undefined` or `null` then the `<a>` won't have an `href`

Comment: In my case, that variable is pointing to an exported string variable. Any reason it would be `null/undefined`?

Comment: Can you `console.log` that variable to see its value?

Comment: It is `undefined`.. very weird.. not sure if you have any suggestions as to why it would be undefined, but i'll accept this answer as the original question was answered.

Comment: Ok i figured it out - because i was using `jest` and `SOME_URL` is an exported string value from a different file, i had to mock it in my test file..